# how to read ajax results as an array instead of a string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Environment: PHP  5.3.5  MySQL Server 5.5.8

Created my first ever ajax call and after much determination I have got results. The results appear to be returning as a string. for when I request

`alert(result[0]);`

I am only returned a single character.

If I try to use a field name, I have a value of undefined returned.

Here is the javascript for my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "models/ajaxHandler.php", 
    data: "handler=this&stu=21", 
    success: function(result){ 
            if (result !== null) 
            { 
                    alert(result + " " + result[0] +" " result['firstname']);  
                    var obj =  JSON && JSON.parse(result) || $.parseJSON(result);
                    alert(obj + " " + obj[0] + " " + obj['firstname']);
            } 
            ShowDialog(false); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
    }, 
    error: function()
    { 
            alert("ajax failure"); 
    } 
});
```

So once the result is captured using a PDO connection in PHP to mysql with a fetchAll(). I return the results from the php like so:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

The alerts for the results comeback like so:

> [{"firstname":" Test","0":" Test","lastname":" One","1":"
>   One","id":"2","2":"2","st_usage_id":null,"3":null},{"firstname":"
>   Mr","0":" Mr","lastname":" Two","1":"
>   Two","id":"3","2":"3","st_usage_id":null,"3":null},{"firstname":"
>   Mr","0":" Mr","lastname":" Three","1":"
>   Three","id":"5","2":"5","st_usage_id":null,"3":null}]  [  undefined

The parse of the JSON returns all results as object.

I have also tried returning the results in php using:

```
print_r(json_encode($results));
```

It displays the same string above. Lastly I used

```
$var_dump(results);
```

This returned the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(7) " DrTest"
    [0]=>
    string(7) " DrTest"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(4) " One"
    [1]=>
    string(4) " One"
    ["user_public_info_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["st_usage_id"]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(3) " Dr"
    [0]=>
    string(3) " Dr"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(4) " Two"
    [1]=>
    string(4) " Two"
    ["user_public_info_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["st_usage_id"]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(3) " Dr"
    [0]=>
    string(3) " Dr"
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(6) " Three"
    [1]=>
    string(6) " Three"
    ["user_public_info_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["st_usage_id"]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
}
 a undefined
```

I am not sure what it is I am missing, and I'm sure it is something simple. I feel like I have tried everything. Please could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: I tried traverseing through the results usiong the following snippets too. The results always returned undefined (indefinitly)

$.each(result, function (i, elem) {
            alert(elem.firstname);
         });

Comment: `alert(obj[0]['firstname'])`

Comment: And this is the other attempt:

result.foreach(function(entry){
                            alert(entry);                        });

Comment: tried that too. the second alert does not work.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the issue. I was accessing the elements of the obj as a single array item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to accept an answer:

Try:

```
alert(obj[0]['firstname']);
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify the json datatype.

```
dataType: "json"
```

Note, the result will never be `null` in recent versions of jQuery, instead it'll go to error in the event nothing gets returned.

Comment: What DID it do? this definitely should make `result` an array rather than a string.

Comment: Kevin, dataType is a case sensitive word, so that was caught and the error was message was displayed. If I return the results using echo ($results) the result in ajax is detailed above. When I tried 

var obj = $.parseJJSON(result);

The output was [object Object]. If I removed it, it was the same result. 

I was not using a double array to access the unique elements of the array. 

I see your point thought if nothing is returned and I will have the datatype defined. Thank you.

Comment: If you're getting `[object Object]`, then it's working. `alert(result[0].firstname)`

Answer (score 1):

Add "results = $.parseJSON(result);" to the beginning of your success call and it should turn it into a Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php, states that when the second parameter of json_decode is true, "returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

This should do it for you:

```
$results = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: This seems almost redundant. I don't get why you'd suggest to encode results than to decode them. Doesn't that just undo what was done? 

Anyhow the result was I was not treating the results returned by Ajax as a double array.

Comment: @user2672744 Did you try it?